# Store characters in a 2 dimensional array instead of ASCII values

Tags: java, arrays, oop

I created a method to store '-' as a blank space into a 2 dimensional array but after compiling it stores the number 45, which is the ASCII value of '-' character. Can somebody please tell me how I can actually store the character and not the ASCII value?

```
private int[][] array;
public final char BLANK = '-';
public BlankArray(int gridSize)
{
    array = new int[gridSize][gridSize];
    for(int row = 0; row < gridSize; row++) {

        for(int col = 0; col < gridSize; col++) {

            array[row][col] = BLANK;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: I'm glad you want to participate, but it's  not clear which language you're writing in. Please edit your question to add the appropriate tags.

Comment: Also, you appear to want one character code to magically morph into a different one.  Why not just use `' '` for `BLANK`?

Comment: i could use just ' ' but i want to specify my blank spaces as '-', so that it is visually more interactive.

Comment: Hint: you have to understand that information and representation aren't the necessarily the same thing. You decided for whatever reason to have **array** to use **int** values. Ints are first and foremost **numbers**. The fact that 45 happens to be the dash character when using that number as character ... is well: you mixing up two things. Put the information into your array that helps you getting your task down. Then think how to reasonable **display** the contents of that array.

Comment: I don't see any reason why you need the array to be of type int when you already want to store chars. If you need to read the ascii value you may still do so even if it is a char 2d array. In fact, be it you are using int or char, both ways are feasible.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared a two dimensional array of type integer. The blank character is being implicitly cast to type integer. If you wish to store the character in your array, declare your array as type char rather than int.

Comment: i need the array to be an integer type....is there any other way to fix it while keeping the array of  int type?

Comment: Yes, you can retain the int array, however the ASCII value will be stored in the array. You can then cast the value back to type char when needed, e.g. char value = (char)array[row][col];

Comment: im confused....can i just typecast it within this line?                                array[row][col] = BLANK;

Comment: BLANK is of type char, however array[row][col] is of type int. You will only be able to store the int representation of BLANK, i.e. 45, in array[row][col]. You can explicitly cast this as array[row][col] = (int)BLANK;

Answer (score 0):

**You can print the stored ASCII value "45" as "-" by using :**

```
System.out.print(" "+ (char)array[row][col]);
```

**Consider this Example program :**

```
class fun {

    public int[][] array;
    public final char BLANK = '-';

    public void BlankArray(int gridSize) {

        array = new int[gridSize][gridSize];
        for (int row = 0; row < gridSize; row++) {

            for (int col = 0; col < gridSize; col++) {

                array[row][col] = BLANK;
            }

        }
    }

    public void printArray(int gridSize) {

        for (int row = 0; row < gridSize; row++) {

            for (int col = 0; col < gridSize; col++) {

                // System.out.print("array ["+row+"] ["+col+" ]" +
                // array[row][col]);
                System.out.print(" " + (char) array[row][col]); // casting ASCII
                                                                // value to char
                                                                // at the time
                                                                // of printing
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

}

public class int_array_char {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        fun obj = new fun();
        obj.BlankArray(4); // passing 4 as gridSize

        obj.printArray(4);

    }
}
```

> Note: just type cast at the time of printing.